# How to override my database in fastapi? i cannot override my database

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I want to use another database when running a test how do I override my current database here at my test.py. I want the current database url override on my pytest
**test.py**

```
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from main import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    yield TestClient(create_app())
```

**Database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from async_generator import asynccontextmanager
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

from app.config import settings

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = settings.sqlalchemy_database_base_uri.format(
    mysql_host=settings.mysql_host,
    mysql_user=settings.mysql_user,
    mysql_password=settings.mysql_password,
    mysql_db=settings.mysql_db,
    mysql_charset=settings.mysql_charset,
)

engine = create_async_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)

@asynccontextmanager
async def create_session():
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        async with session.begin():
            yield session

async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)

Base = declarative_base()
```

**Settings.py**

```
from functools import lru_cache
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str = "My App"

    # Logger
    log_level: str
    log_format: str

    # MySQL
    mysql_host: str
    mysql_user: str
    mysql_password: str
    mysql_db: str
    mysql_charset: str

    # SqlAlchemy
    sqlalchemy_database_base_uri: str
    sqlalchemy_track_modifications: bool

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"


settings = Settings()
```

**.env**

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_BASE_URI=mysql+asyncmy://{mysql_user}:{mysql_password}@{mysql_host}/{mysql_db}?charset={mysql_charset}&binary_prefix=true

SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=True
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DB=my_db
MYSQL_CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**App/**init**.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.api.client_profile.route import router as client_profile_router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(client_profile_router)

def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()

    init_routers(app)
    init_logging()
    init_database_service(app)

    return app


def init_logging():
    from app import logging
    logging.init_logger()


def init_database_service(
        app: FastAPI
):
    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup():
        # create db tables
        from app.service.database.database import Base, engine
        async with engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


def init_routers(
        app: FastAPI
):
    app.include_router(client_profile_router)
```

**main.py**

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

I tried to override it but it always uses the current database. how do i override this?

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is a way to separate your settings by environment (production, testing, development). This is a quality of a [12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).

For settings management, I usually build my settings module like so:

```
import os
from functools import lru_cache

from pydantic import BaseSettings


class DefaultSettings(BaseSettings):
    mysql_host: str
    mysql_user: str
    mysql_password: str
    mysql_db: str
    mysql_charset: str = “utf8mb4”


class ProductionSettings(DefaultSettings)
   class Config:
       env_file = “.env”

class DevelopmentSettings(ProductionSettings):
    mysql_host = “localhost”
    mysql_user = “my”
    mysql_password = “foo”
    mysql_db = “my-dev-db”
    class Config:
        env_file = “.development.env”


class TestingSettings(DevelopmentSettings):
    pass


@lru_cache
def get_settings():
    mode = os.getenv(“MYAPP_MODE”)

    if mode in (“dev”, “development”):
        return DevelopmentSettings()
    if mode in (“test”, “testing”):
        return TestingSettings()
    return ProductionSettings()
```

With this, your settings are controlled by your MYAPP_MODE environment variable. I generally default to production, that way I don’t accidentally turn on debug/dev stuff that my settings may control when in dev mode.

I don’t always use a special testing env, but often times I’ll have a different database for my test suite than for my development env.

I declare all of my “required” settings in DefaultSettings so that I get an error on startup if I’ve forgotten to set one rather than waiting for my app to blow up because of a missing value.

When you run your test suite, set MYAPP_MODE to test or dev. When you’re in your dev loop, set MYAPP_MODE appropriately. I usually set it in my editor’s launch configuration.